# Tell salt to ask for password when switching user

Tags: salt-stack

I'm running salt under unprivileged user. The idea is to make some states that can be executed under different unix users, but without giving root privileges to anybody who executes the state. So the question is if it is possible to somehow tell salt to ask for password when switching the user either via runas or when specifying user like in cmd.run. Effectively I would like to achieve something like:

```
salt '*' cmd.run runas=myuser ask_for_pass=true 'whoami'

test1:
    > enter pass for myuser:
    'myuser'

or in the same in a form of state:
whoami:
    cmd.run:
       - user = myuser
       - ask_for_pass = true
```

or one more example that is closer to what i'm actually trying to achieve - installing jboss for a different user (salt-minions and master are running as user "salt"):

```
$ salt 'host1' state.jboss runas=jboss_user ask_for_pass=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Salt doesn't do exactly what you're wanting to do here.

Your best bet would probably to use the `client_acl` or `external_auth` master config options.

These both will allow you to give either a system user or ldap user the rights to run specific commands.

`client_acl` docs for authorizing system users: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clientacl.html

`external_auth` docs for authenticating external users from PAM or LDAP: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/eauth/index.html

So for example, if you had set up LDAP external_auth, you could require your users to do the following on the command line:

```
salt -a ldap '*' state.jboss
```

Salt would then prompt the for a user and password.

Comment: As far as i understand probably the closest thing to what i need would be to use LDAP as the auth but somehow find the way to classify/group the states that can be executed by group of people. I don't know if it is possible, but may be having state.dev.jboss and then allow everybody who is in dev group to execute state.dev.* - is this possible?